# Writing to a pipe in linux using php

Tags: php, c, linux, named-pipes

I have created a pipe in linux `mkfifo /tmp/myFIFO` now i have set the chmod to 777.. then i have a c application which reads the pipe and output what i wrote to the pipe.

When i do it this way in php and this works..

```
$command = "echo 'helloworld' > myFIFO";
$process = proc_open($command, $descriptor, $pipes, $cwd, $env);
```

but when i do it with fwrite e.g

```
$out = fopen("/tmp/myFIFO","w");
fwrite($out,"hello");
fclose($out);
```

It does not work at all. I'm not getting any output from my pipe in linux?..  Why is that fwrite is not working?.. thanks

Comment: did you check if the fopen succeeds? It returns boolean false on failure. e.g. `$out = fopen(...) or die('unable to open file');`.

Comment: have you tried `$out = fopen("/tmp/myFIFO","a");` to append instead of truncate?

Comment: not yet wait gonna try that one out. i'll update you asap.

Comment: Are you certain your paths/working directories are correct? Your `fopen()` code uses an absolute path but your `proc_open()` example uses relative paths.

Comment: I'm getting unable to open file.. why is that?.. i set the chmod to 777 but why can't i open it?

Comment: @DaveRandom - Yes im using a relative path.. /tmp/myFIFO

Comment: Is your reader process definitely running?

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(~0);` place it on top of your script, add the exact error messages you get to your question. Just for the troubleshooting and you don't fly blind.

Comment: Thanks i just solved it. just problem with chmod.. changed 777 to a+rw

Answer (score 3):

It's working now thanks for all your help. I set the chmod to a+rw.

```
chmod a+rw /tmp/myFIFO
```

Now it's working fine now.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

FIFOs have the strange behavior that when you first `open` them for writing (either directly with the `open(2)` system call or via any wrapper such as `fopen(3)`), the `open` call blocks until a reader also opens the same FIFO for reading.  When both ends have opened, the two calls are unblocked, and reading and writing can commence.

What you're probably seeing is that your program is never getting to the `fwrite` call (which should function normally) because the `fopen` call never returns, since no reader has opened the other end of the FIFO yet.  If you have another program open up the FIFO for reading, it should work.

Comment: btw what is the numerical equivalent of a+rw?

Comment: @demic0de `chmod 777` is the same as `chmod a+rw`

Comment: `777` is not the same thing as `a+rw`. In general symbolic modes do not have numeric equivalents, because the symbolic mode can ignore certain bits (e.g. `a+r` does not affect the existing write or execute bits), so for any given file the resulting number depends upon the original number.) `777` *will* typically be the same thing as `a+rwx` as you are setting all of read/write/execute together (but note that there are other mode bits besides those ones).

Comment: @demoic0de: mkfifo honors the umask, so you should do `$old = umask(); umask(0); mkfifo(FIFO, 0777); umask($old);`

Comment: **666** is the equivalent of "a+rw".  It's (all, add read and write, or) rw-rw-rw-.

777 is a+rwx, or rwxrwxrwx.  It includes "execute" permission.  I don't know what, if anything, execute permission would do for a FIFO.

Comment: @Jeffiekins: That's an interesting question—there's no meaningful usage of that that I'm aware of.  I did an experiment: `mkfifo fifo; chmod a+x; ./fifo`, and to my surprise, Bash opened up the read side without error.  I wrote a little shell script to it `echo -e '#!/bin/bash\necho hi > fifo` from another shell, at which point the first shell died with `bad interpreter: Permission denied`.  I'm speculating here that when it tried to execute the FIFO, it might have tried to `mmap()` the file into memory, which is likely where the permission denied error may have came from.

Comment: Thanks for doing an experiment, and some intelligent speculation about your results.

Comment: @Jeffiekins: I repeated the experiment under `strace`.  On the read/exec side of the pipe, Bash executes `execve("./fifo", ...)`, which initially blocks and then later fails with `EACCES` once the write side of the pipe is opened.  Conversely on the write side, the pipe is opened successfully, but then the call to `write(1, "#!/bin/bash\n", 12)` fails with `EPIPE` and the process receives a `SIGPIPE`.  So clearly the OS/program loader are not happy to try to exec a program from a pipe.

Comment: [Here's the check](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/exec.c#n862) in the guts of the `execve()` implementation that checks that the file being executed is a regular file, after resolving any symlinks.  If it's anything else like a pipe, socket, block device, or character device, the `S_ISREG()` check will cause `do_open_execat()` to fail with `EACCES`.